# access run time macro is failing on 'quit'

Tags: ms-access

When I run a macro it is halting on '   DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone'
it says 'quit is not available now' 
what do I need to do to correct this?

```
Public Function UnassignedPayments()
    Dim XFile As String

NPDateB = Date
        NPDateE = Date

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        XFile = "I:\Management Reports\Unassigned Payment Analysis Report.pdf"

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Unassigned Payment Analysis Report", acFormatPDF, XFile
            DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveNone
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.Quit acQuitSaveNone`, it shouldn't cause this error.